# how do you reach a secure shell server connected to a virtual private network?

Tags: ssh, vpn, routing

Simply put :
Laptop running ssh and connected to a vpn.
How do I ssh to it ?

I get the external ip with a google search, my router forwards port 22 on the laptop and I can connect with success when openvpn doesn't run.
It seems to me that when I enter the external ip on my ssh app, it will try an ssh connection on the vpn server, not comming back to my machine.

I need some clarifications please don't be harsh.

Here are the routing tables once openvpn is started.

```
default via 10.247.202.221 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
10.247.200.1 via 10.247.202.221 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.247.202.221 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.247.202.222 metric 50 
154.16.48.155 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.14 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 proto static scope link metric 600 

default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp2s0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 scope link
```

Answer (score 0):

If your OpenVPN doesn't use port 22, then the problem is most likely that OpenVPN changes the default route.

You could reach the laptop via VPN.

If you want to reach the laptop through its normal address while the VPN sets the default route, it's a little tricky, but possible with policy based routing. If you want to do this, leave a comment and I can describe how to do it.

**Policy based routing**

Normally you have one routing table that is consulted for all outgoing packets. With policy based routing you can can use different tables that are used for different types of packets.

In your case, the VPN creates a default route to the VPN, which you want to use for most connections. The problem is not packets reaching your machine, it's the return packets that go to the VPN instead of to the originator.

You first need a rule to match packets originating from the local interface.

```
ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table 200
```

The `200` is somewhat arbitrary, see `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and don't use any of the predefined values 253-255. You can also add a number and a name to that file and then refer to the table by name. This causes all packets with a source address in `192.168.1.0/24` to use `table 200` instead of the default routing table. Now we must add rules to this table. I will assume that your normal table just contains entries for the local network and the gateway to your router.

```
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp2s0 table 200
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table 200
```

You must add the route to `192.168.1.0/24` although it is already present in your default routing table.

Now the response for all incoming packets to your address 192.168.1.14 should go out through `wlp2s0` to your router, while the response for all incoming packets to your VPN address should go back to the VPN.

If it doesn't work, use `tcpdump -i any port 22` to see what packets are received and sent. If you need port 22 to connect to your external server to test, then forward a different port in your router to your laptop and use that port to test. For this test it doesn't even matter whether the port onyour laptop is open or not. If you see a response, run `tcpdump -i wlp2s0 port 22` and try again. If you don't know how to interpret the result, append them to your question.

Comment: I just read what you told is about helping me to reach the laptop by discarding the vpn settings, that is not what I am lookinf for, I need to be able to get a shell inside the tunnel

Comment: I added a description for policy based routing. You should be able to connect with SSH both through VPN and without.

Comment: So I tried to logicaly understand and reflect what you said but the truth is that I will NEVER be a network administrator.
Then I dully input the commands you gave me and replaced eth0 with my wifi interface and the 192.168.0... by the appropriate 192.168.1... that we get in france.
Wont work. But it leaves me in pain, the pain of knowledge that grows... thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `ip route; ip route show table 200`? There is nothing special about 192.168.1 and France, it's just the default setting of your particular router.

Comment: I post that in the edited question !

Comment: I added suggestions for further diagnosis.

Comment: before we try any further I have to tell you I contacted the vpn support and the guy told me that this was impossible since they don't forward ports. I've heard of remote shells (exploit shells) even through a vpn without any prior configuration ; so does it all depend on the provider configuration ? What puzzles me is this: ALL trafic MUST get through 443 via the router to get to the vpn server, then ALL responses come back to the router on 443, what next ? What makes a torrent client work then ? when openvpn gets packets from the router it dispatches them to the appropritate port/app ?Thanks

Comment: and this is the link cyberghost's support send me 
https://torrentfreak.com/huge-security-flaw-can-expose-vpn-users-real-ip-adresses-151126/

Comment: When you have VPN active, do you try to connect to the original external address of your router or to the external address of the VPN gateway?

Comment: I'm trying to reach the VPN gateway

Comment: The you just need a port forwarding from the VPN endpoint to your port 22. The article you mentioned would prevent that from your own laptop, but why would you connect from your laptop to your laptop through VPN? It should work from any other device. It thy don't forward ports at all, then you have to connect to your router's external address, like you do if VPN is not running.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarifications and your benevolence. I'm just concerned about anonymity, to answer your question. Wonder if I can ssh through tor... lol